# Checking remainder in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am super new at Javascript. I'm trying to write a script that logs numbers in order, and then at the end tells me if the final number is even or odd.

What I have is:

```
var i = 0;

  do {
    i++;
    console.log(i)
    }

 while (i <= 9);

 if(i % 2 = 1) {
   console.log("odd")
   }

 else {
   console.log("even")
    }
```

Before I added the if/else, it worked. Now I keep getting the error: invalid left-hand side in assignment

What am I doing wrong? And to really display my ignorance, what is the left-hand side in the assignment?

Thanks!

Comment: `==` for checking equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it says invalid left-hand side, it means that you are trying to assign a value to something on the left side. You have used -

```
if(i % 2 = 1)
```

However, = is an assignment operator, which basically assigns a value to a variable on the left. What you need is == which is a comparison operator since you are trying to compare two values.

This should be your code -

```
if(i % 2 == 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you will want to use the double equal (`==`) or the triple equal (`===`), when checking your remainder, since the single equal (`=`) is used to assign values to variables.

Difference between `==` and `===`:
`===` is more strict than `==` since `===` checks the value AND type whereas the `==` only checks the values.

Example:

```
if(1 == '1') // true
if(1 === '1') //false : their types are different.
```

Secondly, you will likely want to wrap your `if` statement inside of your `do-while` loop to get an output of `even` or `odd` after logging each number.

Here is the final result:

```
var i = 0;

do {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  if(i % 2 === 1) {
    console.log("odd");
  } else {
    console.log("even");
  }
} while (i <= 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `=` it should be `==` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Simple typographic errors should be answered in the comments and flagged for closure.

Answer (score 2):

you need to   change if condition from  `if(i % 2 = 1)`
to

```
if(i % 2 ==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i % 2 == 1) {
   console.log("odd")
}else {
   console.log("even")
}
```

Because `==` is for equality comparison while `=` is for assigning of value.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem in you code is , you are using an assignment operator "=" in your if condition, instead use "==" (comparision operator).

You can find more information on comparision operators in Javascript here :
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp